# Backbone View Assign Template to el

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Is it ok to assign the @template() to an @el like this:

someview.js.coffee

```
class SomeView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["app/templates/sometemplate"]

  events:
    'click' : 'onClick'

  initialize: ->

  render: ->
    @el = @template()

  onClick: ->
    #do something
```

index.js.coffee

```
class IndexView extends Backbone.View
  initialize: ->
    @collection.on('reset', @render, this)

  render: ->
    $(@el).html('')
    for m in @collection.models
      view = new App.Views.SomeView(model: m)
      $(@el).append(view.render().el)
```

sometemplate.jst.hamlc

```
.someview_template
  .stuff_inside
```

The situation I'm in, the SomeView class is being wrapped with a div and it's making me lose the click event I want assigned directly on the '.someview_template' element. The way I can think to solve this is by reseting the @el = @template()... is that possible or the right way to do this?

Is it the case that the @el of Backbone.View should always be the containing div, and the template should be only the elements contained within that div? Seems like it would be more basic if @el is automatically set to the root node found in the @template(). Should I just let the sometemplate.jst.hamlc contain only ".stuff_inside", then in SomeView set $(@el).addClass('someview_template'), that way I can be sure the events are assigned to that element?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not okay for a couple reasons:

1. You'll lose the event bindings on `@el` so none of your events will work.
2. The cached `@$el` won't match `@el` anymore.

If you want to replace the `@el`, use [`@setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement):

> **setElement** `view.setElement(element)`
>
> If you'd like to apply a Backbone view to a different DOM element, use **setElement**, which will also create the cached `$el` reference and move the view's delegated events from the old element to the new one.

You probably want something more like this:

```
render: ->
  @setElement(@template())
  @
```

Comment: ok, so i should do so using @setElement. i also updated my post, if you don't mind looking. just a general question about how i should set this up from the start, should i always assume that my Backbone.View is going to be the root node and the template should be nodes contained within? or is it better to just set the entire markup it with @setElement(@template())?

Comment: @kurtybot: The usual pattern is to leave `@el` as a container and then `render` puts things inside that container. I think `@setElement` is mostly for special circumstances. You can use [`tagName`, `className`, ...](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) to define `@el`. The template usually just contains the content for `@el`.

Comment: yeah, that is the way i'm going to do it from now on. just let the Backbone.View itself be the root node and let templates be the content within that root node.